In John 3:8, contextually, what does Jesus refers to, the Spirit's work of regeneration or the transformational effects in the believer's life?
Text: John 3:8 (NET)

The wind blows wherever it will, and you hear the sound it makes, but
do not know where it comes from and where it is going. So it is with
everyone who is born of the Spirit.


The work of the Spirit (the baptism of repentance and the being born again) within a person are only visible (to others) due to 1. Faith in Christ according to correct doctrine 2. Conduct which is suitable to accompany that doctrine. Are these the 'transformational effects' to which you are referring ?

Yes, the 'transformational effects' I’m referring to are the visible changes in faith and conduct that result from being born again. My question distinguishes between the Spirit’s initial work of regeneration (being born again) and the ongoing transformation in a believer's life that follows, and Jesus' use of the analogy in the text was about the transformation part rather than the regeneration.

Nicodemus was chided by Jesus for not knowing what his theological training and knowledge ought to have prepared him for. He had been schooled in the Hebrew scriptures, and would have known (and sung) the Psalms from his early days.
There was one particular Psalm that should have enabled Nicodemus to begin thinking along the correct lines when Jesus spoke of the mysterious work of the invisible Holy Spirit in causing individuals to be drawn to true worship. This Psalm spoke of God's mysterious drawing of non-Jewish people into being born (spiritually) and thus being identified with God's people. Here is the relevant part:

"Glorious things are spoken of thee, O city of God. I will make
mention of Rahab and Babylon to them that know me: behold Philistia,
and Tyre, with Ethiopia: this man was born there. And of Zion it shall
be said, This and that man was born in her: and the highest himself
shall establish her. The Lord shall count, when he writeth up the
people, This man was born there." Psalm 87:3-6 A.V.

None of those people from non-Israelite countries were ever born, literally, in Zion, City of God! Yet three times the Psalmist records under inspiration of the Holy Spirit, that a whole raft of Gentile peoples would be counted as "Zion-born". Further, that God himself would establish this and 'count' those people as born in his 'holy mountain'.
So, when Jesus speaks three times of the Spirit of God in John chapter 3, he prefaces those three times with his admonition to Nicodemus,

"Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water and of
the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God. That which is
born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of the Spirit is
spirit." John 3:5-6 A.V.

And then Jesus concludes with a rebuke - after Nicodemus continues to show his spiritual unawareness:

"Art thou a master of Israel, and knowest not these things?" vs. 10

There seems to be every indication that, in that chapter, Jesus is teaching Nicodemus about the first, essential, mysterious working of the Holy Spirit to bring about the new (spiritual) birth from above. Until that first truth is understood, believed, and in operation, there can be no work of the Holy Spirit to work transformationally. The person has to first be regenerated. Only thereafter will the Holy Spirit progress that person's faith so that it can be seen that their life is being transformed.
That section about Nicodemus ends at verse 21, where nothing is said about a person's life; 'only' about their condemnation having been removed. This means that my answer is that Jesus restricts his words in verse 8 to the invisible, mysterious initiative of the Holy Spirit in regenerating individuals. Indeed, for the whole first 21 verses, Jesus says nothing about the transformation in a believer's life after the new birth.

As with all biblical questions that can be addressed with hermeneutics, context is the primary factor: Who is speaking, who is the audience, and what are the circumstances.
In this case, Jesus is answering a question from a highly educated, elite Pharisee named Nicodemus. Nicodemus had expressed astonishment regarding Jesus’ assertion that he must be “born again” or “born anew” from above (see SG 509).

Jesus answered, “Truly, truly, I say to you, unless one is born of
water and the Spirit, he cannot enter the kingdom of God. That which
is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of the Spirit is
spirit. Do not marvel that I said to you, ‘You must be born again.’
The wind blows where it wishes, and you hear its sound, but you do not
know where it comes from or where it goes. So it is with everyone who
is born of the Spirit.” – John 3:5-8 ESV

So, in this context, how would you interpret verse 8 regarding the wind? There seems to be three primary choices:
A.  Jesus is suddenly providing Nicodemus valuable meteorological information about the circularity of air flow in weather cyclones around low pressure areas along with a prophetic hint of Chaos Theory in dynamic systems that would be first observed by meteorologist Edward Lorenz in the 1960s, over 1,900 years later!
B.  Jesus is suddenly providing Nicodemus valuable insights into Pneumatology, a term that’s derived from the Greek words, pneuma, which can mean wind, breath, and spirit, and logos, which has a semantic range encompassing message (primarily), concept, reason, and plan. Thus, Jesus here reveals a dynamic dissonance to the concept of the Holy Spirit as a personal being at the exclusion of the concept of an impersonal spiritual force as exemplified in 2 Kings 2:9-11 regarding Elisha receiving a “double portion” of the Holy Spirit.
C.  Jesus tells Nicodemus that just as he’s clueless about how wind works, he should not expect to understand (or control) the comings and goings of those people who have been “born of the Spirit.”
D.  A muddle of portions of all three above, added to a chunky stew of theology and doctrinal positions.
Which one would you pick?
However, Nicodemus answers Jesus as follows:

Nicodemus said to him, “How can these things be?” – John 3:9 ESV

This is a scholarly articulation of the more common uneducated response, “Wut?” or “I don’t get it.” Jesus goes on to identify an unwillingness by Nicodemus to believe rather than an intellectual objection. However, we learn in John 7:51 that Nicodemus later stands up to the fury of the Pharisees, by asking them

“Does our law judge a man without first giving him a hearing and
learning what he does?” – John 7:51 ESV

His question to the other Pharisees and chief priests was not well received, and they contemptuously accused him of being “a Galilean” and gave him a homework assignment.
Then, in John 19, we read that Nicodemus apparently became a believer in Jesus, spending what must have been a fortune in money for funerary spices.

Nicodemus also, who earlier had come to Jesus by night, came bringing
a mixture of myrrh and aloes, about seventy-five pounds in weight. –
John 19:39 ESV

I believe the answer to the earlier question when taken in context to the conversation is C.

John 3:8 serves as evidence that being a believer in Christ is not by our works, but by the grace of God.

The wind blows wherever it pleases. You hear its sound, but you cannot tell where it comes from or where it is going. So it is with everyone born of the Spirit. (NIV)

In both Greek and Hebrew, the word "wind" is synonymous with the "Holy Spirit". The wind doesn't blow randomly, it targets specific individuals as He pleases. As stated in Luke 2:14:

“Glory to God in the highest heaven,
and on earth peace to those on whom his favor rests.”

You hear the whisper of the Holy Spirit not because of your own ability, but because he allows you to. You will never know how it begins, nor can you tell where he will guide you. Your regeneration or transformation depends on his work; it is a grace from God for the elect. As 1 Peter 2:9 states:

But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, God’s special possession, that you may declare the praises of him who called you out of darkness into his wonderful light.


Good points, but would it not have been more accurate to switch from 'it' [the wind] to 'he' [the Holy Spirit] when you spoke of his initiatives?

@Anne - Thank you and it is a good advice.

John 3:

6 That which is born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit.
7 Marvel not that I said unto thee, Ye must be born again.
8 The wind bloweth where it listeth, and thou hearest the sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh, and whither it goeth: so is every one that is born of the Spirit.

Three simple facts:

Those that are born of the spirit are spirit.
The saved will be reborn as spirit.
Spirit beings can be invisible, moving wherever they want.

1 Corinthians 15 describes how the saints will be reborn as spirit at Christ's return:

50 Now this I say, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God; neither doth corruption inherit incorruption.
51 Behold, I shew you a mystery; We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed,
52 In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.
53 For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.

John 20 describes how on two consecutive Saturday nights, Jesus, now an immortal spirit being, suddenly appeared from nowhere, without having to use the door:

19 Then the same day at evening, being the first day of the week, when the doors were shut where the disciples were assembled for fear of the Jews, came Jesus and stood in the midst, and saith unto them, Peace be unto you.
…
26 And after eight days again his disciples were within, and Thomas with them: then came Jesus, the doors being shut, and stood in the midst, and said, Peace be unto you.

Jesus gave Nicodemus a simple description of how saved Christians will be transformed from flesh into spirit at his return.

In John 3:8, contextually, what does Jesus refers to, the Spirit's work of regeneration or the transformational effects in the believer's life?

Neither.
Jesus is simply saying that as a spirit being one will be able to move around invisibly, passing through walls, and materializing anywhere.

Just read what Jesus and others actually said and wrote, and accept it for what it says; it really doesn't need to be complicated.

You wrote, "Jesus is simply saying that as a spirit being one will be able to move around invisibly, passing through walls, and materializing anywhere." I don't agree that this is what Jesus is actually explaining to Nicodemus. In my view, Jesus is presenting to the highly educated Nicodemus an analogy between Nicodemus' expected ignorance of meteorology with his expected ignorance of people "having been born of the Spirit" from above. +1 for everything else. :-)
